# Finding the predicate of a sentence:

Tags: python, tree, dependencies

For an example, we have a sentence saying `"I just played the biggest event in the world"`. The predicate here is the `"played"`.

I know that I should tokenized the sentence and then use the nltk to find its dependency of each word. However, I do not know how to identify which is the predicate.

Another example,

`"I played football with friends and I hit a goal"`. Here the predicates are `"played"` and `"hit"`. Is there a way to find it? I tried to use the dependency tree. I somehow, get the idea that the head of the tree should be the predicate but then when comes to two or more predicates. Which should I find?

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: The worst thing is I do not have any attempt yet because I dont even know where I could start from.

Comment: From memory (and I only skimmed) I believe this chapter discusses this : http://www.nltk.org/book/ch09.html